# Share PC internet with Android and then through WiFi-HotSpot

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android

#### The setup:

- PC with internet connection. (Windows and Linux OS)
- Android phone *without* internet.
- Another device *without* internet, that I want to connect to internet through WiFi from first Android phone's `WiFi-HotSpot`.

#### The question:

Is it possible to share PC's internet with Android phone, and then through Android's `WiFi-HotSpot` share it to other devices?

#### What I tried so far :

The first what I find out is `Reverse tethering`, through USB/Bluetooth/Wifi, then enable the `WiFi-HotSpot` and then check other devices WiFi... No luck, that didn't work, there were no internet on the wifi hotspot, since the way that reverse tethering *gives* internet to the Android phone(actually some apps won't even see the connection on the phone which reverse tethering) not the way that `WiFi-HotSpot` can share... Is there any way to make `Reverse tethering` to *give* internet connection like `mobile data` or some other way that could be shared through `WiFi-HotSpot`?

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is not supported out of the box on most Android devices, for the same reasons given by davidgo. However there are some workarounds;

Basically what you want is a wi-fi repeater and/(or) wifi-extender functionality and you can achieve this with some third party applications;

There is an application that I tested with this functionality

[NetShare tethering (no root) application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kha.prog.mikrotik&hl=en) is  a solution to the problem addresed.

> Now this application uses a vpn proxy to route traffic from device
>   connected to Wi-Fi network to another client via a p2p connectivity.

Thus allowing to "share wi-fi over wifi" or act as a repeater
 through **Wi-Fi direct**

- Essentially, it uses a HTTP proxy to route traffic to the client and configuring the connection is fairly easy:

In this case since you're using two Android devices, then simply install the application in both devices share the internet on the primary device and let the secondary device "join":

[image] [image]

1. Firstly connect the primary Android device to the PC internet.
2. Start the application and share the internet from the primary device, and in the secondary device, join that network and input necessary credentials. (Or manually add the wireless access point if not done already, and input the Wi-Fi direct Group password).
3. After this the secondary device can now access the shared internet connection.

   *Note: You may need to configure proxy settings to;*

   `Server: 192.168.49.1`

   `Port: 8282`

Comment: Thanks, that is the one of ways of doing that what I wanted, do you know any ways to do this through usb/bluethoot? PC(with internet), AP1(Without internet), AP2(Without internet). Connect AP1 to PC with reverse tethering, and then share "that" to AP2, possible? not? **Wifi-hotspot** the reverse tethering through USB...?

Comment: You can check some of the methods I described here: [Different ways of sharing interet connection from Windows to other devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/171049) Some may need rooted devices

Comment: There were no method that I was looking for, but method 4 is very similar, but instead of Windows ICS, I'd like to share 3(a/b)'s internet through Android's *WiFi-Hotspot feature*, so that AP2 could receive **reverse tethered** internet through *WiFi-hotspot* of AP1, but as you said, the reverse tethering works not for all apps, so that's why it won't be shared through *WiFi-hotspot*... I'we been trying that and it didn't worked... Thanks anyway. P.S. I need the exact opposite of what OP asked in the question you mentioned: INTERNET>PC>USB>AP1>WIFI>AP2,AP3,etc.

Comment: @BladeMight, Oh I understand what you want to achieve, it is a bit complicated though it may be possible, but so far I haven't managed to successfully foward a 'reverse-tethered' internet connection via usb, but will update if I do get something along the lines :)

Comment: OK, I looking forward to see it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not really doable on Android - generally speaking WIFI devices (on Android)  can be either an access point or a client, but not both.

I do note it may be technically possible (ir some hardware in some phones may support it), but this is not a general function built into Android.

Comment: So, no way? Really? Too bad :/

Comment: But what about `mobile data` sharing through wifi-hotspot, if it would be possible to reverse tether the internet as *mobile data*, I think it should be possible to share it through wifi-hotspot, am I wrong?

Comment: @BladeMight - Took me a while to understand what (I think) you are saying, which would, I guess, be to have the PC as an AP client and the second android device as an AP client, with the first Android phone as the AP (ie hotspot).   This might be indeed be possible if you can use static IP addressing on all the devices and turn your PC into a router - and, most importantly - if hot-spotting does not isolate clients.

Comment: What about USB? Is it possible through USB or Bluetooth?

Comment: The hardware is capable of this.  Don't know about the software.

Comment: Well, looks like no one ever done this...

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not possible cause every device has to have it's own IP address. If you tether the lan internet, you only get 1 IP for your device. If you share it, it's still just 1 IP address. I guess we need some sort of app that tells the PC to pull out an IP for all new connected devices